# Get all liquidity in all dex of a token

Tags: solidity, web3js, decentralized-exchange, 1inch-dex-aggregator

Is there a way to get all the liquidity of a token? Also locked and burned liquidities, actually my aim is to build something similar to token sniffer, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the factory abi of all dexes to get liquidity for the mostly used tokens from front end. Eg. the factory address of pancakeswap is `0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73`. The abi of pancakefatory have a function named `getPair(address token1, address token2)`. Then in front end with web3 or etherjs you will initialize factory contract.

Here is the simple example for finding single pair:

```
const [pair, setPair] = useState("")
const token1;
const token2;
const pancakeFatory = new ethers.contract(factoryContract, abi, provider)
const setPair = async () => {
  const pairAvailable = await pancakeFactory.getPair(token1, token2);
  setPair(pairAvailable)
}
```

If you have multiple factories and multiple tokens to check like usdt, bnb, eth, btc etc then you have to utilize nested loop and if pair returned is 0 address then the pair is not available and pair returned is not a zero address then pair is available.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was really great, now is there a function that I can get all the pairs and find out from it if my token is zero or token one is the token I am checking and filter it?  And is there a way I can calculate the locked and burned liquidity?